# How can I reduce my repeated jquery codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
jQuery('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner-und').change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val() == 0) {
    jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-one').nextUntil('.form-actions').find('input, select, textarea').val('');
    jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-one').nextUntil('.form-actions').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-one').nextUntil('.form-actions').find('select').trigger("chosen:updated");
  } else if (jQuery(this).val() == 1) {
    jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-two').nextUntil('.form-actions').find('input, select, textarea').val('');
    jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-two').nextUntil('.form-actions').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-two').nextUntil('.form-actions').find('select').trigger("chosen:updated");
  } else if (jQuery(this).val() == 2) {
    jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-three').nextUntil('.form-actions').find('input, select, textarea').val('');
    jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-three').nextUntil('.form-actions').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-three').nextUntil('.form-actions').find('select').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }
});
```

Comment: Local variables

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out, the main thing to simplify your code is storing intermediate steps in variables. I want to add encapsulating conditional checks in a data-structure:

```
jQuery('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner-und').change(function() {
    const $this = jQuery(this);
    const labels = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    const target = $this.parent()
        .parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner')
        .siblings(`#edit-field-beneficial-owner-${labels[+$this.val()]}`)
        .nextUntil('.form-actions');

    target
        .find('input, select, textarea')
        .val('');

    target
        .find('input:checkbox')
        .attr('checked', false);

    target
        .find('select')
        .trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

Comment: How could I miss that? Kudos! Deleted my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a local variable for the result of the "base" of all of the things you're working with. Then, you can make a function to handle the steps you were typing out repeatedly.

```
jQuery('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner-und').change(function() {
  let numOwner = jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner');
  let handle = function(sibs) {
    sibs.nextUntil('.form-actions').find('input, select, textarea').val('');
    sibs.nextUntil('.form-actions').find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    sibs.nextUntil('.form-actions').find('select').trigger("chosen:updated");
  }

  if (jQuery(this).val() == 0) {
    handle(numOwner.siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-one'))
  } else if (jQuery(this).val() == 1) {
    handle(numOwner.siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-two'))
  } else if (jQuery(this).val() == 2) {
    handle(numOwner.siblings('#edit-field-beneficial-owner-three'))
  }
});
```

Comment: Your code is working. Thank you so much. But I have to check for 20 people.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways you could handle this. Here is one example.

Map your value 0-2 into the string equivalent. Use the value as the index into the array to get the string (notice the back-ticks that allow you to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ). Store the long series of jQuery calls into a variable, and use that variable for the `find()` calls.

```
jQuery('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner-und').change(function() {
  let ownerMap = ['one', 'two', 'three']
  let owner = jQuery(this).val()

  let formAction = jQuery(this).parent().parent('#edit-field-number-of-beneficial-owner').siblings(`#edit-field-beneficial-owner-${ownerMap[owner]}`).nextUntil('.form-actions')
  formAction.find('input, select, textarea').val('');
  formAction.find('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false)
  formAction.find('select').trigger("chosen:updated")
});
```

Comment: "Store the long series of jQuery calls into a variable, and use that variable for the find() calls." is working. But entire code is not working. I don't know which part is wrong. But it seems everything is correct.